# How to make absolute element automaticaly resize with parent heigh?

Tags: css, styles, absolute

I'm having hard time trying to solve this problem :(
I'm developing a React application to train myself.

The basic structure of my application looks like this :

```
<body>
 <Component />
 <AnotherComponent />
 <AgainAnotherComponent />
 ...
</body>
```

All of these components have a css attribute `min-heigh: 100vh` to make sure that they all takes the device heigh.

Inside one of these components, I have an element in `absolute` position with the css attribute `heigh: 100%`.

When the parent composant of this element, by default, is at `100vh` heigh, nothing is wrong, the absolute child element is taking all of his parent heigh.

But the problem is that when the parent have a lot of contents to display and its heigh is **more** than `100vh` (`150vh` for example) due to the `min-heigh: 100vh` attribute, then the absolute child heigh stuck at `100vh`.

After several hours of researchs and attempts, I'm hoping someone there will help me .. 
Sorry for my poor english skill, I hope it's understandable

Mecadie

**EDIT** https://antoine-regembal-portfolio.netlify.com
Here is the webapplication hosted on Netlify, the absolute element is the github panel located on the Projects section (on the right)

Answer (score 2):

There are two things at play here:

1. Setting `height: 100%` on the child container constrains it to however tall the first parent container with `position: relative` is, in this case I'm assuming your `min-height: 100vh` parent container. Per @focus.style's answer, `top: 0; bottom: 0;` will have the exact same behavior, because of the second point:
2. Because your child container is absolutely positioned, it is taken out of the document flow. This means that, if your child container content exceeds the height of the parent container, it won't increase the height of the parent container.

The combination of these two things is what's causing your child to remain at 100vh height.

If all you want is for your child to expand in height, try `min-height: 100%` instead of `height: 100%` on the child element. However, point 2 above still holds, so the parent container will not expand. To make the parent container expand, you'd have to keep your child in the document flow.

Here's a quick Codepen demonstration: https://codepen.io/samsonzhangthesalmon/pen/rNVPxrj

Comment: Hi thanks for you answer !
I used the @focus.style solution "parent element position: relative;"

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using **heigh: 100%** for child element with absolute positioning, try to use

```
top: 0px; 
bottom: 0px;
```

But it is too few information to deal with in your example. Need some more code.

Or try this

```
.presentation, .projects {
    min-height: 100vh;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    color: #fff;
    position: relative;
}
```

Comment: Hi, I've tried this tricks but then the absolute element was moved on the top of the page, here is the webapp for you to look what is the problem https://antoine-regembal-portfolio.netlify.com

Comment: Oh. And did you try to make it's parent element position: relative; ? It's the most important step.

Comment: Oh man ... this is the solution ... I thought `position: relative` was set by default ... 
How hard it is to find ou the solution is that simple ! Many thanks !

Comment: edited an answer so you can mark it as the right one

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution that worked for me, given by focus.style

> Oh. And did you try to make it's parent element position: relative; ? It's the most important step. –